# Unity - Resolve implementation of generic interface based on model type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to Unity and am running into issues when it comes to classes that implement generic interfaces.

Suppose I have one controller and one service class, with the intention that they call the business layer based on an type identifier passed into the controller.  Here's my layout:

Models:

```
public interface IModel
{
    string Name { get; }
}
public class MyOrder : IModel
{
    public string Name { get { return "Order"; } }
}
public class MyInvoice : IModel
{
    public string Name { get { return "Invoice"; } }
}
```

Business Logic:

```
public interface ILogic
{
    string GetModelName(IModel myModel);
}
public class MyOrderLogic : ILogic
{
    public string GetModelName(IModel myModel)
    {
        return "MyOrderLogic : " + myModel.Name;
    }
}
public class MyInvoiceLogic : ILogic
{
    public string GetModelName(IModel myModel)
    {
        return "MyInvoiceLogic : " + myModel.Name;
    }
}

public class LogicFactory
{
    Func<IModel, ILogic> logicResolver;

    public LogicFactory(Func<IModel, ILogic> resolver)
    {
        logicResolver = resolver;
    }

    public ILogic GetLogicForModel(IModel model)
    {
        return logicResolver(model);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class MySingleService
{

    private LogicFactory factory;

    public MySingleService(LogicFactory f)
    {
        this.factory = f;
    }

    public IModel GetModel(int typeId, int objectId)
    {
        IModel model;
        // This would really call Entity Framework context
        switch (typeId)
        {
            case 1:
                model = new MyOrder();
                break;
            default:
                model = new MyInvoice();
                break;
        }
        return model;
    }

    public void DoSomething(IModel model)
    {
        var logic = factory.GetLogicForModel(model);
        var name = logic.GetModelName(model);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController
{
    MySingleService service;

    public MyController(MySingleService s)
    {
        this.service = s;
    }

    public void DoAnAction(int typeId, int objectId)
    {
        var model = service.GetModel(typeId, objectId);
        service.DoSomething(model);
    }
}
```

This all works pretty well when I configure my Unity container like so

```
var container = new UnityContainer();            
container.RegisterType<ILogic, MyOrderLogic>("MyOrder");
container.RegisterType<ILogic, MyInvoiceLogic>("MyInvoice");

Func<IModel, ILogic> resolver = (myModel) => container.Resolve<ILogic>(myModel.GetType().Name);
var logicFactory = new LogicFactory(resolver);
container.RegisterInstance<LogicFactory>(logicFactory);

var controller = container.Resolve<MyController>();
```

My issue is that I want to restrict the Business Logic classes so that they can only work on the proper model (i.e. I want MyOrderLogic to only accept MyOrder)

I wanted to have the business layer make use of generics, like so:

```
 // Business Logic
public interface ILogic<T> where T : IModel
{
    string GetModelName(T myModel);
}
public class MyOrderLogic : ILogic<MyOrder>
{
    public string GetModelName(MyOrder myModel)
    {
        return "MyOrderLogic : " + myModel.Name;
    }
}
public class MyInvoiceLogic : ILogic<MyInvoice>
{
    public string GetModelName(MyInvoice myModel)
    {
        return "MyInvoiceLogic : " + myModel.Name;
    }
}
```

This caused all kinds of problems between the Service and the Controller.  I'm not sure how to properly resolve the *Logic classes based on a type identifier.  I tried to do something similar to `ILogic<IModel> logic = new MyOrderLogic()`, but that obviously didn't work.

Is what I'm looking for possible?  Is there something I can add to just the `LogicFactory` or something?

I want to avoid having individual controller and service objects as they would just have duplicate code.

Comment: For DI, you should probably have something like `IOrderLogic` and `IInvoiceLogic`.  Your existing classes can still implement `ILogic`, but don't wire up `ILogic` for DI; you can pass an `ILogic` into another service that doesn't care what logic it is performing, but services that require Order or Invoice logic should have specific parameters for those types (`IOrderLogic` or `IInvoiceLogic`, or their concrete implementations).

Comment: The factory would determine which type to implement (order or logic).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm hoping to avoid specific implementation in the Service layer, as it's that part will be executing the exact same code for both types.  The only difference is the final step of calling the business layer specific to the model.

Comment: *I want to avoid having individual controller and service objects as they would just have duplicate code.* - That means this is an example of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You seem to be creating abstractions for the sake of making abstractions without considering their actual benefit. If you can do without the controllers, then you should be customizing routing to allow one set of controllers to do all the work, and not be tinkering with this level at all. Conceptually, it's sensible to make orders separate from invoices, though because they do different things (w/shared svcs).